# How to find the composedBy relation in dbpedia?

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, ontology, dbpedia

Look at this query:

```
construct {?symphony dct:composedBy  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Symphonies_by_Ludwig_van_Beethoven>}
{
?symphony dct:subject <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Symphonies_by_Ludwig_van_Beethoven>
}
```

You can run it over this endpoint:
http://dbpedia.org/sparql/

You will get results, so far so good:

I tried to get the music work for Beethoven by using the **dct:subject**, well ... that's no so correct, because it lists just the symphonies, there *should* be a relation to list all the works for Beethoven, including sonatas and strings ... **do you know that property please?**

Plus, I tried the subject property on some opera composers and the results were films that use the opera's opening for that composer as the theam for that movie. so we can see that the *subject* property is not good to get the musical works, i am looking for help to find something like composed by

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> here should be a relation to list all the works for Beethoven, including sonatas and strings

I don't see why that's necessarily the case;  DBpedia only contains what people put into it, and that information, even if it's present in Wikipedia, isn't necessarily stored in a way that DBpedia can extract it.

It looks like you've got a reasonably good handle on how to explore DBpedia data, though, and that same kind of process can be helpful here.  But if you're interested in what links to Beethoven, then you can have a look at the corresponding resources.  This may have varied results.

For instance, if you look at the [resource for Für Elise](http://dbpedia.org/page/F%C3%BCr_Elise), you'll see there's no property directly linking it to the composer (and since those pages show properties in the reverse direction, too, there's no link from Beethoven to the piece, either).  That's enough to show that DBpedia doesn't necessarily have the data you're looking for.

However, there is a property that might be useful, **dct:subject dbc:Compositions_by_Ludwig_van_Beethoven**.  Based on that, you might be able to modify your query to use something like:

```
?symphony dct:subject dbc:Compositions_by_Ludwig_van_Beethoven
```

That's no guarantee, but this process of exploring the data looking for relevant bits is probably the best bet for finding this information.

Comment: hello, thanks for answer, actually, i've already saw the compositions by ludwig van beethoven, and in my case, i changed that to a class not a property, it is like the 9th symphoney is **rdf:type** **compoitions by beethoven**. i know that dbpedia is not enought, but the other options are so bad, for example to use music ontology, i had to go to

Comment: I had to go to music ontology, and they send me to linked branis, which sent me to another dataset (music something i don't remember), but that one is 2.6 GB triples, extracted from a relational database, there is no owl ontology corresponding for that data, though

Comment: though there is a music ontology but i am not able to find tirpes for it, i tried like three month ago to find something and i check almost all the internet for owl music and corresponding triples, but nothing, and now since a week i am trying again but

Comment: but no success so i though i build one using dbpedia data, but also that data is not complete :( I just need some property for the music pieices, such as key, composed by, style, and some properties for the composer, and some properties for the classes that the symphony (and other music works like sonata) and composers are instances of

Comment: even this query **select *
{
?symphony dct:subject dbc:Compositions_by_Ludwig_van_Beethoven}** doesn't give the symphonies

Comment: look at the result of that query please, how am i going to know the type of each piece? is it symphony? sonata? string? overture? movement? act? .... well i know that myself, but i am not going to do that manualy :)

Comment: @AniaDavid You know how to combine some of these things by now.  E.g., `select ?s {
  values ?c { dbc:Compositions_by_Ludwig_van_Beethoven dbc:Symphonies_by_Ludwig_van_Beethoven }
  ?s dct:subject ?c 
}`  That's not great, obviously, but DBpedia only has what it has.  If you're going to work with DBpedia, you'll have to work around its limitations.

Comment: yes i know dbtune, indeep i spent days and days exploring it and contacting the admins there, the links to rdf dump and sparl end points are not working, and dbtune takes the data from linked brains which is again, not corresponding to owl, and 2.5 is too big. i will try to work with work arround for dbpedia. meanwhile please if you come accrose any data for this ontology http://grasstunes.net/ontology/classicalmusicnav.owl or this http://dbtune.org/cmn/ or this (next comment)

Comment: purl.org/ontology/mo/  any rdf dump (ABox ) for them will be great, i know it is not allowed to ask that, but i mean just if by accedent you heard of something because i know this is your area :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112696/discussion-between-joshua-taylor-and-ania-david).

Comment: hello, how's it going? please could you help me when you have new free time in my new question ?

Comment: Hello, hope you're fine, I just added a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953715/coalesce-not-working-in-this-example and I would like to ask if you can help me there please. it has minimum data and minimum query. appreciate it in advance professor